# How to make Fragment background transparent?

Tags: java, android

I'm using Android Navigation Components with nav_graph and I want to make background of all fragments transparent. I tried to use the code from following resource: [click](https://japp.io/android/create-a-custom-full-screen-dialog-in-android/)
For activity it's working fine, but in fragment background is always white.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        view.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is to set the transparency of the Fragment in the XML.

You can define a transparent color in `colors.xml` like this:
`<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>`

and then reference it in your fragment.xml like this: `android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent"`

Additionally its advisable, to set View-Altering commands into the `onCreate()`.

Also you can define an `android:alpha="0"` attribute in the `.xml` to test if that will set the background color to transparent. But I guess this will only change the opacity of the whole fragment including child elements.